# What is Android mini_emulator image?

Tags: android-source

When building Android,

```
lunch
```

possible images are:

```
 ...
 5. aosp_x86-eng
 6. aosp_x86_64-eng
 ...
 16. mini_emulator_x86-userdebug
 17. mini_emulator_x86_64-userdebug
 ...
```

What is exactly mini_emulator? What is the difference between mini_emulator and aosp_x86?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the configurations here:

- [build/make/target/product/aosp_x86.mk](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:build/make/target/product/aosp_x86.mk)
- [build/make/target/product/aosp_x86_64.mk](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:build/make/target/product/aosp_x86_64.mk)
- [device/generic/mini-emulator-x86/mini_emulator_x86.mk](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:device/generic/mini-emulator-x86/mini_emulator_x86.mk)
- [device/generic/mini-emulator-x86/mini_emulator_x86_64.mk](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:device/generic/mini-emulator-x86_64/mini_emulator_x86_64.mk)

The names of these configurations mean:

- `aosp` means a full-featured Android. Sometimes also refered to as [Generic System Images](https://source.android.com/setup/build/gsi).
- `mini` means a reduced Android.
- `emulator` means that this Android is meant to be run in the `qemu`-emulator.
- `x86` and `x86_64` describe the architecture.
- `eng` [means](https://source.android.com/setup/build/building#choose-a-target)

  > Development configuration with additional debugging tools
- `userdebug` [means](https://source.android.com/setup/build/building#choose-a-target)

  > Like user but with root access and debug capability; preferred for debugging